# How to access to a Many to Many object to get another model property?

Tags: python, django

I'm coding a tooltip for a Django dashboard, so one of the scenarios says that when the user has not connected their Github account the repository link will be disabled. I already solved the problem but I didn't realized that it only works for the owner of the repo, so if I add somebody else as a collaborator, the link is going to work for them, because ofc, they are not the owners.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        TeamMember,
        related_name="github_repos",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )

    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        TeamMember,
        related_name="new_projects",
        blank=True,
        through=ProjectMember,
    )

class TeamMember(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("team", "user_id")

    django_user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="team_member",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, related_name="members", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
    github_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

So basically how I solved the problem was this way:

```
    def html_message(self):
        pattern = re.compile("Github Repository", re.IGNORECASE)

        if self.project.owner.has_connected_github:
            git_connection = self.project.owner.django_user.socialaccount_set.filter(
                provider="github"
            ).first()
            if git_connection:
                html_message = pattern.sub(
                    f"<a href='{self.project.html_url}'>Github Repository</a>", self.message
                )
            else:
                html_message = pattern.sub(
                    f"<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Connect your Github account to access repository.'>Github Repository</a>", self.message
                )
```

That works but as I said before, only for the owner of the app, I need to know how to access to `members`, instead of `owner`, because as you can see is a Many to Many Field.

Any idea how can I access it? I saw similar questions but I don't fully understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Since `members` is a m2m field, you can access `TeamMember` queryset through the `project.members.all()`. It's basically the same thing as `TeamMember.objects.filter(project=self.project)`

In order to show the correct message for a particular memeber, you should have access to this member in your `html_message` method. You probably have a user somewhere in your request or attached to the class. Here is an example:

```
# Pass the user to the method. Maybe you have it in the request.user somewhere near
def html_message(self, user): # or pass a request and then get request.user
    pattern = re.compile("Github Repository", re.IGNORECASE)

    member = self.project.members.filter(django_user=user)

    # It's not clear what your needs if a member does not exist,
    # so I'm taking a shourtcut
    if not member:
        return

    if member.has_connected_github:
        git_connection = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider="github").first()
        if git_connection:
            html_message = pattern.sub(
                f"<a href='{self.project.html_url}'>Github Repository</a>", self.message
            )
        else:
            html_message = pattern.sub(
                f"<a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Connect your Github account to access repository.'>Github Repository</a>", self.message
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally approach it this way

1. Get all `members` in the project

   `all_members = self.project.members.all()`

> this returns a QuerySet

2. Loop through the `all_members` QuerySet and apply same logic you had for the `owner`

Like so

```
for member in all_members:
    if member.has_connected_github:
      .................
```